# FFMpeg undefined reference to get_buffer

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to upgrade the FFMpeg source used with one of our projects but get_buffer has gone away. I'm not 100% sure on which method to replace it with. Here are two contexts in which its used, any help is appreciated.

I look forward to hearing from you soon,

Thanks,
Kevin

```
    cur_offset = avio_tell(pb);
    if (!para->playctrl_info.read_end_flag && (0 == pkt->data_size)) {
        rev_byte = get_buffer(pb, pbuf, para->max_raw_size);
        if ((rev_byte > 0) && (cur_offset <= para->pFormatCtx->data_offset)) {
            try_count = 0;
            pkt->data_size = rev_byte;
            para->read_size.total_bytes += rev_byte;
            pkt->avpkt_newflag = 1;
            pkt->avpkt_isvalid = 1;

  do {
                read_length = get_buffer(s->pb, data + 12, read_size);
                if ((read_length <= 0) || (sync_flag == 1024)) {
                    if (read_length == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        FREE(data);
                        log_error("[%s]get data failed. ret=%d\n", __FUNCTION__, read_length);
                        return 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } while (retry_get_data < am_p->playctrl_info.read_max_retry_cnt);
            pkt = data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you already found your answer I will provide an answer in case others have the same issue. durandal_1707 provided the answer to you (I assume) in #ffmpeg-devel IRC:

> expresspotato: I'm having trouble integrating the latest version of
>   ffmpeg against an old one from about a year and a half ago. It appears
>   get_buffer defined in aviobuf.c has gone away. Do you know which
>   method I should replace it with?
>
> durandal_1707: in [e63a362857d9807b23e65872598d782fa53bb6af](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=e63a362857d9807b23e65872598d782fa53bb6af) get_buffer
>   have been renamed to avio_read